# Drupal custom content type is not displayed

Tags: drupal, permissions

I am building a website using drupal which allows users to create projects and then invite other users to join their projects.

I have created a content type- "project" for the main task. I can successfully edit this content type and publish it, however, when I get to the screen pictured here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DW80.jpg the "view" tab is always empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out Structure > Content Types > manage display, maybe all your fields are set to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

what tulvit said, however...

I would recommend creating a View to display this content anyway. anything generated by the node is always difficult to present as you want, so to solve this issue, just create a View to output the content.